# TYPO3 FlexForm is not appearing

Tags: typo3

This is my code. I don't know where is the mistake? Please refere following code and help me

```
$pluginSignature = str_replace('_','',$_EXTKEY) . '_rock';

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin( 'Rocktechnolabs.' . $_EXTKEY, 'rock', 'THE FAQS' );

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_rock.xml');

in Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_rock.xml

<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <sDEF>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Function</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <switchableControllerActions>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>Select function</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>select</type>
                                <items>
                                    <numIndex index="0">
                                        <numIndex index="0">List</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">Faq->list</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1">
                                        <numIndex index="0">Search</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">Faq->search</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </switchableControllerActions>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </sDEF>
    </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

I tried a lot but i am not getting flexform during select plugin. Can you help me to find out the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the flexform field to the subtypes_addlist:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer..  i have forgotten this, i just added it and it works thanks

Comment: In a case of error it can help to verify the resulting $TCA. You can check what really has been done by TYPO3. Add these lines at the end of the file tt_content.php of your extension. `debug ($GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types'], '$GLOBALS[\'TCA\'][\'tt_content\'][\'types\']');
debug ($GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['list_type']['config']['items'], ' $GLOBALS[\'TCA\'][\'tt_content\'][\'columns\'][\'list_type\'][\'config\'][\'items\']');
`

Answer (score 2):

make sure **your** `$pluginSignature` matches result of `$pluginSignature` within `ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin()`.

This is what's happening in that method:

```
    $extensionName = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $extensionName)));
    $pluginSignature = strtolower($extensionName) . '_' . strtolower($pluginName);
```

To me this looks different :)

Adding `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';` as Rene suggested is important as well.

Comment: I have noted `$extensionName = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY);`. But in connection with the following `strtolower()` while building $pluginSignature all will result in the same if the extension key is build on the usual rules (no uppercase, no spaces). 
And be aware: the constant `_EXTKEY` is not available if you are in /Configuration/TCA/...

Comment: thanks mathias for share knowledge, i am new in typo3 so it will help me lot

yes, i would like to thank bernd too for knowledge in comment :)